# How to be sure that views are saved?

Tags: views

I just had a terrible learning experience. I spent several days building up a bunch of views, only to find that they vanished entirely from my site when I synchronized my configurations to handle another issue. They're gone. I have a dump of the db, but they're not on there either.

The funny thing is that not all of the views are gone. Some that I made several weeks ago are there, but the more recent ones are irrevocably lost.

And yes, I clicked "Save" on each view when I was creating it.

How can I be sure that this never happens again? What steps do I need to take save the views permanently in the db?

Version: Drupal 8.9.6

Comment: Without an extensive log of what you did and what your environment looks like, it's going to be near impossible to answer the question. A good preventative measure here if you're having to switch between configurations as you work on different things, is to capture all your configuration under a sync directory and `git branch` / `drush cex` / `git commit` as you switch around. All the views you add/update should be under `views.view.*.yml` files.

Comment: That's a great tip. My mistake was believing that everything would be saved in the database, too. I will now be doing exactly what you recommended. Thanks, Shawn!

Answer (score 3):

Shawn Conn's answer is what I needed. Going forward, I will now make it part of my routine to take snapshots of my configuration with `drush cex` and commit the changes. My mistake was believing that the views would be saved in the database.

Comment: Just a happy update: I was very relieved to find that my views were able to be rescued from a backup of the database. Do yourself a favor and backup your databases now.